# Dynamically map manyToOne relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create Symfony Bundle in which entities are defined which can be used in a one-to-many/many-to-one relationship without the needing to rewrite the mapping manually.

I do this by subscribing to the `loadClassMetadata` event and adding the mapping based on the Interfaces they implement. It is not as simple as using the `ResolveTargetEntityListener` because that will simply substitute an interface with the concrete class.

An example. I have a Address and a Customer entity. A Customer has many Addresses.
But another bundle may redefine the Customer (or a totally different Entity which can have multiple Addresses). For this reason the Customer implements the `AddressableInterface`. For ease of use I've implemented this interface in a trait.

In the subscriber I check if the class implements the `AddressableInterface`. If so it adds an OneToMany to the `Address` and an ManyToOne to the class which implements the `AddressableInterface`. (In this example the `Customer` class)

However this leaves the following error:

> The association Entity\Customer#addresses refers to the owning side field Entity\Address#subject which does not exist.

But I setup to association both ways in my subscriber.

Below is the essence of my code.

```
namespace Entity;
class Address
{
    public $subject;
}

namespace Entity;
class Customer implements AddressableInterface
{
    use Traits/Addressable;
}

namespace Traits;
trait Addressable //Implements all methods from AddressableInterface
{
    protected $addresses;

    public function getAddresses()
    {
        return $this->addresses;
    }

    public function addAddress(AddressInterface $address)
    {
        $this->addresses->add($address);
    }

    public function removeAddress(AddressInterface $address)
    {
        $this->addresses->removeElement($address);
    }
 }
```

And the event subscriber

```
class DynamicAddressBindingSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [Events::loadClassMetadata];
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $metadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        $class = $metadata->getReflectionClass();
        if (!in_array(AddressableInterface::class, $class->getInterfaceNames())) {
            return;
        }

        $factory = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory;
        $factory->setEntityManager($eventArgs->getEntityManager());
        $addressMetadata = $factory->getMetadataFor(Address::class);

        $addressMetadata->mapManyToOne(
            [
                "targetEntity" => $class->getName(),
                "fieldName"    => "subject",
                "inversedBy"   => "addresses"
            ]
        );

        $metadata->mapOneToMany(
            [
                'targetEntity' => Address::class,
                'fieldName'    => 'addresses',
                'mappedBy'     => 'subject'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

I've looked at multiple examples and based most of my code on [this article](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/) and the Doctrine Bundle source. But I'm stuck at this point because I have no idea why the association can't find the owing side.

Comment: Nice problem, I was just wondering if you really need the reverse relation. Otherwise you wouldn't need to augment the metadata for `Address`. Also it would avoid conflicts in case multiple entities would have addresses in the same application (eg. Company, Person), they can't be both mapped by `subject`).

Comment: Indeed doesn't look like I need the reverse relation, when I remove the metadata for `Address` the error stays the same however.

Comment: Have you removed the `mappedBy` option from the `mapOneToMany` call as well?

Comment: Tried it, but it is manditory for a OneToMany

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your address class doesn't have getter/setter for the subject field.

Another thing is that if you want to bind addresses to any class, you might prefer to make it a manyToMany relations. I do so with attachments like this:

```
$metadata->mapManyToMany([
    'targetEntity' => '...\FilesBundle\Entity\Attachment',
    'fieldName' => 'attachments',
    'cascade' => array('persist'),
    'joinTable' => array(
        'name' => strtolower($namingStrategy->classToTableName($metadata->getName())) . '_attachment',
        'joinColumns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => $namingStrategy->joinKeyColumnName($metadata->getName()),
                'referencedColumnName' => $namingStrategy->referenceColumnName(),
                'onDelete' => 'CASCADE',
                'onUpdate' => 'CASCADE',
            ),
        ),
        'inverseJoinColumns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'file_id',
                'referencedColumnName' => $namingStrategy->referenceColumnName(),
                'onDelete' => 'CASCADE',
                'onUpdate' => 'CASCADE',
            ),
        )
    )
]);
```

where namingStrategy comes from the event:

```
$namingStrategy = $eventArgs
        ->getEntityManager()
        ->getConfiguration()
        ->getNamingStrategy()
;
```

Comment: $subject is actually protected with getters and setters, but I left them out for brevity. 

Any specific reason for ManyToMany, in the article I mentioned they also define a ManyToMany instead of a OneToMany?

Comment: If you allow to mark the relation with the interface, you allow for addresses to be related with any class. While you can have OneToMany introduced dynamically on LoadClassMetadata for a given class, you can not change it dynamically in the database, meaning you cant say "ok this time addresses are related to customers, so 'subject' refers to customers and on another execution change it"
You can only achieve it through M2M and creating a join table for each relation  addresses <> another_class